# Git Tower and PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-tower

For some reason in Git-Tower when I untick the checkbox next to a file in my working copy list it makes it untracked.

That's not what I'm wanting to do. If I uncheck it I just don't want it apart of the current commit I'm about to do.

I still want it to be tracked though. Anyone know why this is happening? I'm also working in the current version of PhpStorm v10.

So after it makes the file in PhpStorm v10 red for the file name I have to make click it and make it added to Git so I'm trying to figure out how to just keep it tracked whole time during development. It does it to all my project files.

Email sent to me.

Roman Koellges (fournova)
Jan 7, 10:31

Thank you for your inquiry.

From what you describe, I'm not sure if I find the "problem" or "bug" in the situation: it sounds as if new files have been created while you were working in PHPStorm - and Tower shows these new files when you switch over to it.
Are you aware that you can add them to Git right in Tower - simply by clicking the checkbox in the Status column? (See attached animated GIF.)

In case I misunderstood your request, here's another take: if you doubt that the "untracked" status for these files is correct, you can check the status simply with Git on the command line. A simple "git status", executed in Terminal.app from the root folder of the repository, should return the same files as untracked.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the ["Staging Changes" documentation of git-Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/working-copy/stage-changes), this should only happen to *new* files, not to files that were previously versioned (and whose new changes you wish to add or not add to your next commit).

[image: http://www.git-tower.com/help/content/01-mac/04-working-copy/03-stage-changes/modified-list.png]

Check first if the issue persists when downgrading git-tower to an older version. If that is the case, it is a bug, to be reported to git-tower support.

And check if this is coherent with a `git status`.

Comment: Not sure why its doing that but I went ahead and made a bug fix issue through their website.

Comment: @user3732216 ok. Do you have a link to that ticket?

Comment: When I got the thank you email it didn't include a ticket number.

Comment: @user3732216 OK, but I suppose there is no way for us to follow the evolution of that ticket. Let us wait and see, then.

Comment: Not that I know of but upon receiving an email I will respond back to this thread.

Comment: Check out my eddited post.

Comment: @user3732216 checking against a git status is certainly a good advice.